# jQuery autocomplete: undefined value pressing the UP arrow key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I am working on an app where I need an input with the [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) function provided by `jQuery`. Everything is okay, until I add some more elements into the `<ul>` where the options are actually added.

What I need, is some 'contextual help' where I can show to the user some basic queries he can enter there.

[image]

They appear and they seem to work, until you press the UP arrow key multiple times. If you are on the first element and press the `up` arrow key, the focus moves to the input. If I press the `up` arrow key again, an error appears and my app crashes:

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at $.(fiddle.jshell.net/_display/anonymous function).(anonymous function).menufocus (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:5831:25)
    at HTMLUListElement.handlerProxy (jquery-ui.js:606)
........
```

The `down` arrow key is working without problems.
You can check a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/adrianpop/p1y2587a/5/) or the one below. 
How to replicate the error:

- Focus on the input box and write `COM`; a dummy autocomplete will apear
- Use the `down` arrow key to move down 1-2 elements; then, use the `up` arrow key to move back to the first element;
- Press the `up` arrow key to move the focus onto the input box
- Press the `up` arrow key again

```js
var tags = ["COMMAND_1", "COMMAND_2", "COMMAND_3", "COMMAND_4"];
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  open: function(e, ui) {
    var autocompleteElement = $('.ui-autocomplete');
    contextualItems = ["COMMAND_1 {item}", "COMMAND_2 {item}", "COMMAND_3 {item}", "COMMAND_4 [{item_1}, {item_2}]"]

    autocompleteElement.append('<li class="ch">Contextual Help</li>');

    for (var i = 0; i < contextualItems.length; i++) {
      autocompleteElement.append('<li class="ui-autocomplete-category" style="background-color: #EEE; padding-top: 5px">' + contextualItems[i] + '</li>');
      console.log(contextualItems[i]);
    }

  },
  source: function(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(tags, function(item) {
      return matcher.test(item);
    }));
  }
});
```

```css
.ch {
  background-color: #EEE;
  border-top: solid 1px grey;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>autocomplete demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
    <input id="autocomplete">

  </body>

</html>
```

I tried changing the Contextual Help in a `div`, I tried to use categories, but I did not succeed. Can you please give me a hint or an idea on how I might solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: The fiddle works fine for me in Firefox, but the stack snippet does show the error. Weird. Edit: right, I didn't check the console

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, the fiddles seem to "work", but the error is there. My real app crashes completely because of this.

Comment: The autocomplete plugin uses `.data()` to associate information with each `<li>` that it creates in the completion list. The problem is that you're adding your own `<li>` with the category, but it doesn't have the data that the plugin expects to be there.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804203/jquery-autocomplete-with-category-selection) is a question showing how to add categories to autocomplete

Comment: @Barmar I don't really want categories, I want something like a separate div where I can put extra things, but I want it to be exactly under the suggestion box. Edit: the answer on that topic also has this bug.

Comment: @Barmar the selected answer in the question you linked has the exact same bug that OP describes. Please link a fiddle that shows the problem having been fixed.

Comment: I doubt this is a bug per se. As @Barmar said, you're most likely not supposed to add elements to `.ui-autocomplete` yourself. If you want context help, you can add an element anywhere else around the dropdown list and update it dynamically.

Comment: @Jeto I'm really curious how do you add elements around the drop down list since the list elements are added to the body (there is the appendTo option but it doesn't help). More exactly, how to you make them to dock to the suggestion list that appear only when you write something.

Comment: @Adi See below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I doubt you're supposed to manually change the contents of `.ui-autocomplete`.

What you can do instead is add a contextual help element outside of the dropdown and position it dynamically upon `focus` (or any other event, depending):

```js
var tags = ["COMMAND_1", "COMMAND_2", "COMMAND_3", "COMMAND_4"];
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(tags, function(item) {
      return matcher.test(item);
    }));
  },

  focus: function(event, ui) {
    $('[data-context-help]')
      .css({
        top: $('.ui-autocomplete').position().top + $('.ui-autocomplete').outerHeight(true),
        left: $('.ui-autocomplete').position().left,
        width: $('.ui-autocomplete').outerWidth(true)
      })
      .text('Help for ' + ui.item.value)
      .show()
  }, 
  
  close: function(event, ui) {
    $('[data-context-help]').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.ch {
  background-color: #EEE;
  border-top: solid 1px grey;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
  <input id="autocomplete">

  <div data-context-help class="ch" style="display:none">Help goes here</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I love it! With some minor tweaks, I managed to implement it into my app and it works perfectly. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Jquery-UI's autocomplete always will create a menu with an `items` option that accepts all children as menu items. Unfortunately, it's hardcoded in the autocomplete class. You can change the option to avoid selecting elements that aren't proper items, but JQuery recommends against changing it after the menu is already created.  Still, you can still do it, and it seems to work for me.  To change the `items` option in the `ui-menu` that is created after the autocorrect input, I did:

```
$("#autocomplete ~ .ui-menu").menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category):not(.ch)" );
```

In my example, I used the sibling selector so that you can have it particular to the autocomplete id (assuming there's only at most one autocomplete per container) if you want to. Whatever is the best way for you to select the `ui-menu` is what you should use; this was just an example.

```js
var tags = ["COMMAND_1", "COMMAND_2", "COMMAND_3", "COMMAND_4"];
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  open: function(e, ui) {
    var autocompleteElement = $('.ui-autocomplete');
    contextualItems = ["COMMAND_1 {item}", "COMMAND_2 {item}", "COMMAND_3 {item}", "COMMAND_4 [{item_1}, {item_2}]"]

    autocompleteElement.append('<li class="ch">Contextual Help</li>');

    for (var i = 0; i < contextualItems.length; i++) {
      autocompleteElement.append('<li class="ui-autocomplete-category" style="background-color: #EEE; padding-top: 5px">' + contextualItems[i] + '</li>');
      console.log(contextualItems[i]);
    }

  },
  source: function(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(tags, function(item) {
      return matcher.test(item);
    }));
  }
});

$("#autocomplete ~ .ui-menu").menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category):not(.ch)");
```

```css
.ch {
  background-color: #EEE;
  border-top: solid 1px grey;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
  <input id="autocomplete">

</body>

</html>
```

**JSFiddle at:**

https://jsfiddle.net/p1y2587a/7/

Comment: It would be nice if you made a stack snippet instead of jsfiddle.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I added one just now.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!